# How to Multiply two numbers in php

Tags: php

1)I am retrieving the deduction data from db as `1000.00` and its type is in double(10,2)

2) And i have calculated monthly salary based on working days as shown below,
i am getting out put of `$emppp` as `2898.00`;

3) Now i am trying to subtract deduction(1000.00 which is from db)from salary then its showing the error like this

> A non-numeric value encountered

```
<th class='text-right'>".$emppp-$total_did;echo"Rs</th>

$amounts=round($employee_salary/$days);
$amountss=$amounts;
$emp_salary=number_format($totaldays*$amountss,2);
$emppp=str_replace(',','',$emp_salary);
```

Comment: `1 * 2` <- just use `*`

Comment: _“Now i am trying to subtract deduction”_ - the code you have shown does not seem to contain any actual subtraction operation.

Comment: **Always** store money values as whole integers and divide on output by 100 to get the float. This avoids many rounding problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is like this:

1.get `$emp_salary` by doing `$totaldays*$amounts`. (don't use `number_format()` there)

2.Now subtract deduction amount from `$emp_salary` and then use `number_format()`

Sample code:

```
<?php

$employee_salary = 45000.00; //assumed

$days = 29; //feb month total days

$totaldays = 20; //days user is present in office

$deduction = 10000.00; // you gave it in your question

$amounts = round($employee_salary/$days);//get per day salary

$emp_salary= $totaldays*$amounts; // get total salary based on days user is present in office

echo $emppp= number_format($emp_salary-$deduction ,2); // now remove deduction amount and use number_format()
```

Output: https://3v4l.org/O8PO1

More reduced code: https://3v4l.org/oftfC